# one dropdownbutton many values

Tags: flutter, dropdown, form-fields

I have a problem: How can I have two different values in one dropdown button?

Example:

`animals: dog, cat, caiman.`

`Fruits: mango, tomato, watermelon.`

I want animals and fruits to be in fat and dog, cat, caiman, mango, tomato, watermelon to be in italic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_smart_select](https://pub.dev/packages/smart_select). It allows you to design the options/choices in the dropdown and also you can show them in groups as you have stated in your question.